# School timetable in flutter

Tags: flutter, timetable

I want to make a school timetable in flutter and I tried anything but I didn't found a solution yet.

[**How can I make something like this?**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAY9x.jpg)

Comment: check [DataTable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=6&v=ktTajqbhIcY&feature=emb_logo)

Comment: If you want customized one, you should go with @pskink suggestion to use DataTable or you could also use https://pub.dev/packages?q=timetable one of the packages from pub dev.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I am trying the DataTable method.

Comment: I tried to make a DataTable, but the Containers are not expanding properly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.